# Ошибка LDAP подключения к Service Desk

Tags: ldap

При попытке настроить подключение по LDAP к домену, вылезает ошибка: javax.naming.NamingException: a problem with GSSAPI occurred - couldn't create a GSSAPI directory context
Скорее всего ругается KERBOS. Подскажите, в чем может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: Ошибка возникает в Naumen SD, c naming OU и employee 
При необходимости могу отправить часть скрипта.